# Create Conda Environment by Connecting to Existing Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have Anaconda installed on a server. I have a conda environment on a NAS. The conda environment is not visible to the Anaconda installation, because it was created with a different installation on a different server.

Is it possible to "create" a conda environment from my Anaconda installation that would actually bypass creation and just point to the existing environment on the NAS? This would be similar to using the `--fake` method in Django to connect to existing tables when a model is migrated.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you could try sourcing the `etc/profile.d/conda.sh` from your conda installation on the NAS and then create the environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either add the location of the directory containing the environments to your conda config, which tells conda where to "look" for environments, or you can just activate the environment directly by passing the path.

Assuming your your NAS is mapped to a drive letter (such as Z:) and your conda environment is located at `Z:/conda/envs/my_env`, then you can add that location to your conda configuration via:

```
conda config --append envs_dirs Z:/conda/envs
```

Now when you can activate the environment using:

```
conda activate my_env
```

If you have another environment named `my_env` in a different directory, it will be first in the order.

Alternatively, you can activate the environment directly by passing the path.

```
conda activate Z:/conda/envs/my_env
```